TenantGuidNotFound when trying to send email using Microsfot GraphAPI
I am trying to send an email using Microsoft GraphAPI inside my Laravel app. I am able to successfully get an access token through this function.
public function getAccessToken() {
        $tenantId = 'someID';
        $scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';
        $appId = 'someAppID';
        $secretId = 'secretID';
        $secret = 'someSecretString';
        $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{$tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token?scope={$scope}&client_id={$secretId}";

        $config = [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => $appId,
            'client_secret' => $secret,
            'scope' => $scope,
        ];

        $response = Http::asForm()->post($url, $config);

        $data = $response->json();

        $token = Arr::get($data, 'access_token');
        
        return $token;
    }

When I decode the received access token using jwt.io, I get this.
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/**********************/",
  "iat": 1727514977,
  "nbf": 1727514977,
  "exp": 1727518877,
  "aio": "k2BgYGiT2uLUtyghU2/p5IaN16YKAAA=",
  "app_displayname": "Mailer Oauth2",
  "appid": "***************************",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/***************************/",
  "idtyp": "app",
  "oid": "c4addf3b-ab49-4270-bbf8-a2a4d832c560",
  "rh": "0.ARMBkUlDtYDgK02i7VB0sFJDagMAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAAAUAQA.",
  "roles": [
    "Mail.ReadWrite",
    "Mail.ReadBasic.All",
    "Mail.Read",
    "Mail.Send",
    "Mail.ReadBasic"
  ],
  "sub": "c4addf3b-ab49-4270-bbf8-a2a4d832c560",
  "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
  "tid": "*************************************",
  "uti": "bC3CrECPGEOLobarnNDrAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "0997a1d0-0d1d-4acb-b408-d5ca73121e90"
  ],
  "xms_idrel": "10 7",
  "xms_tcdt": 1727427193
}

Under the roles attribute, I can see that Mail.Send is present.
When I try to send an email using this code
$emailData = [
            'message' => [
                'subject' => [$this->subject],
                'body' => [
                    'contentType' => 'HTML', 
                    'content' => $newTemplate, 
                ]
            ],
                'bccRecipients' => [
                    [
                        'emailAddress' => [
                            'address' => $this->mails->toArray()
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'attachments' => [
                    [
                        '@odata.type' => '#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment',
                        'name' => basename($srcImage),
                        'contentBytes' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($srcImage)), 
                        'contentId' => 'image', 
                    ],
                ],
        ];

        
        $response = Http::withToken($this->token)
            ->post("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{$this->email->email}/sendMail", [
                'message' => $emailData['message'],
                'saveToSentItems' => 'true', 
            ]);

But I receive this error
{"error":{"code":"OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound","message":"The tenant for tenant guid '***************************' does not exist.","innerError":{"oAuthEventOperationId":"d630a3bf-f7b2-4373-872f-6618f21d7429","oAuthEventcV":"bXHKl4PYUfE8FIF62ShkHA.1.1","errorUrl":"https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant","requestId":"e131128d-d6f1-43da-85ac-88799cac7cac","date":"2024-09-28T09:30:39"}}}
This is a screenshot from my Azure app (App Permissions tab)

I have searched the internet and found out that I should use keyword 'common' when obtaining an access token, instead of using actual tenantID... I have tried it, but I receive error that tenantID is invalid and I can't obtain access token.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?scope={$scope}&client_id={$secretId}

I have selected multitenancy inside the Azure app, as you can see on the screenshot:

Honestly, I am not very experienced with Microsoft Azure... I assume the problem might be in some Azure definitions, but I have no idea where. Any help is appreciated.

The problem was in the getAccessToken() function. I was sending a request to the wrong endpoint, and therefore the obtained access token was wrong. The correct endpoint URL is
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

More info on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=http

A similar question was asked at Microsoft. The top answer is

Error 401 Unauthorized 'OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound' occurs
when your Azure AD does not have Office 365 account to work.
If you want to access your messages for your development O365 tenant, register the app in your O365 AAD tenant that you got when you created the development tenant.
Please follow the below steps:

You need Microsoft 365 account with subscription
In your Azure portal login with your Office 365 account
Create app in Azure active directory under App registration and give permissions according to the documentation
Then use your messages endpoint for users

You were getting user data users/{users-id} with this API because its Azure AD endpoint
When I decoded your token I found that you were using Application
token for me/messages endpoint.
You need delegated token with permissions 'Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite' to use 'me/messages' endpoint.
Hope this helps.
If the answer is helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and kindly
upvote it. If you have further questions about this answer, please
click "Comment".

Another answer says:

To resolve this issue, I replaced the tenant ID with the keyword
common in the authorizationURL and tokenURL. This allows users from
any Azure AD tenant, including personal Microsoft accounts, to
authenticate. Below is my oAuth strategy Code.

import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-azure-ad-oauth2';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import axios from 'axios';

@Injectable()
export class OauthStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'azure-ad') {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService
  ) {
    super({
      clientID: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_CLIENT_ID'),
      clientSecret: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
      callbackURL: this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_CALLBACK_URL'),
      authorizationURL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
      tokenURL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
      scope: [
        'openid',
        'User.Read',
        'profile',
        'email',
        'Mail.Read',
        'Mail.ReadBasic',
      ],
    });
  }

  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    params: any,
    profile: any,
    done: VerifyCallback
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const userProfile = await this.getUserProfile(accessToken);
      const user = await this.authService.validateUser(userProfile);
      if (!user) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
      }
      done(null, user);
    } catch (error) {
      done(error, false);
    }
  }

  async getUserProfile(accessToken: string): Promise<any> {
    const graphUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';
    const response = await axios.get(graphUrl, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });
    return response.data;
  }
}

So, you will either need to make sure your tenant is properly prepared and then you can pass the id of it like in your URL of "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{$tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token?scope={$scope}&client_id={$secretId}", or replace {$tenantId} with common in it.
